# Fixed point implementation of int min

Tags: c++, max, min, fixed-point, numeric-limits

I am reading about positive and negative infinity in c++ and i am trying to implement them in a fixed point math arthimethic implementation

i can see that max of a int will be equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` 
in c++

and min value of the int will be equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::min();`
in c++

Here as i am defining the int max and int min manually in my fixed point math implemenation, my doubt is     `int min = -int max;` or `int min = -int max -1;` ?

can someone clear it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your sign representation, but I will assume it is two's complement.

In that case, we have `-x = ~x + 1` so `x + (~x) = -1` for every signed integer x.

So `int min = (~max) + -1 = - ( (unsigned int) max) + -1`

Comment: even i assume it as two's complement so its int min = -intmax -1 ?